# How to make a slanted css background without transparency overlapping?

Tags: css, background, border, transparency, overlap

I've got a website I'm designing to be a single page with multiple sections that have slightly transparent backgrounds. In my design one of the sections trails off diagonally to reveal whatever the background underneath is. Because they're transparent every time I've tried to make a rotated background it's overlapped and looked gross. So I thought I could make a border and get rid of one of the corners somehow so it slants properly without touching the other section but I can't get it to slant properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/c9P8Q/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="page2">
   <div class="angle">
       border here
   </div> 
   <div class="floated-content">
       <p>floating content, Lorem ipsum whatever</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.angle {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.9);
    border-bottom: 40px solid rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.9);
}
```

Ideally I need the slant to just sit inside the .angle class. But I'm not sure how to go about this. Any help is much appreciated x

---

EDIT:

Solution in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/qHAK7/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    .angle:after { width: 0;
height: 0;
content: "";
border-top: 41px solid #3498db;
border-right: 36px solid transparent;
position: absolute;
right: -36px;
top: -1px;
}
```

try this code and make ur .angle{width:70%} like this[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aashi/c9P8Q/6/)

Comment: This really helped me out! It wasn't 100% what I was after but it was enough to point me in the right direction for the solution, cheers for your insight man! JSfiddle of the solution here: 

http://jsfiddle.net/qHAK7/2/